# Return scrollbar when user clicks outside of popup to close it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jQuery code that removes the scrollbar while the popup modal is open. So, when I need to close popup, the scrollbar needs to appear again and the function works as intended except for one thing: if the user clicks elsewhere outside of the popup it will close, but the scrollbar remains hidden. It only works fully as intended when the close icon is clicked.

Is there any possibility to set auto overflow scrolling when the user clicks outside of the popup box? i.e. Not just on the close icon?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("button#mainbtn").click(function (){
     $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');  
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.closer',  function (){
     $('body').css('overflow', 'auto'); 
 });
 });


 <div id="myModal" class="modal" >
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="closer">&times;</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Code that opens modal box:

```
 var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
 var btn = document.getElementById("mainbtn");
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closer")[0];
 btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
 }

span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

css:

```
 .modal {
  display: none; 
  z-index: 100; 
  padding-top: 100px; 
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  }


.modal-content {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
margin: auto;
position:relative;
width: 60%;
height:90%;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.closer {
top:0px;
right:20px;
 color: #00284d;
position:absolute;
font-size: 45px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have attached an event to close the modal, if they click outside of it you can set the overflow to auto just after you hide the modal.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a `$("html").click(function()` and check if your popup is visible or hidden. The function is executed every time a click is made on the entire page

```js
$("html").click(function() {
  if($('.popup').is(":visible")){
  alert("visible: dont show scroll")
  }
  else{
  alert("hidden: show scroll")
  }
});

$("button").click(function() {
   $('.popup').toggle();
  });
```

```css
body{
background-color: blue;
height; 1000px;
width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="popup">popup</div>
<button>toggle popup</button>
</body>
```